# Opened rate of Firebase notification is not getting calculated on console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

Opened rate of Firebase notification is not getting calculated on console for all the notifications.

[image]

In few forums, it is advised to wait for 48 hours to get the analytics but in our case, analytics for opened notification are not reflecting.

we already have included both : compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0' compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0' in gradle.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue but on iOS only and think it might be due to conflicting analytics libs?

Comment: I am having the same issue and there seems to be very few resources concerning this

Comment: Any solutions? I have the same issue still in 2018 :-)

Comment: Same issue here on Android and iOS